# How to set values in the listbox?

Tags: dropdown, abap, dynpro

I have defined a list box in my selection screen, as follows:

```
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK B2 WITH FRAME TITLE ALTITLE1.
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF LINE.
SELECTION-SCREEN COMMENT (30) ALCONT4 FOR FIELD L1.
PARAMETERS: L1 AS LISTBOX VISIBLE LENGTH 20 MODIF ID AOD.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF LINE.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK B2.
```

Now I need to propose possible values for that list box, how can I do it ?

Answer (score 4):

During the PBO of your screen (for selection screens, the PBO code is defined inside the event block [`AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapat_selection-screen_events.htm)), you must call the function module `VRM_SET_VALUES`, passing the name of the field and a list of values.

```
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK b2 WITH FRAME TITLE altitle1.
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF LINE.
SELECTION-SCREEN COMMENT (30) alcont4 FOR FIELD l1.
PARAMETERS: l1 AS LISTBOX VISIBLE LENGTH 20 MODIF ID aod.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF LINE.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK b2.

INITIALIZATION.
  alcont4 = 'Choose the country'(001).

AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT.
  DATA: lt_value TYPE vrm_values,
        ls_value TYPE vrm_value.
  ls_value-key = 'DE'.
  ls_value-text = 'Germany'.
  APPEND ls_value TO lt_value.
  ls_value-key = 'FR'.
  ls_value-text = 'France'.
  APPEND ls_value TO lt_value.
  CALL FUNCTION 'VRM_SET_VALUES'
    EXPORTING
      id              = 'L1'
      values          = lt_value
    EXCEPTIONS
      id_illegal_name = 1
      OTHERS          = 2.
```

Execution:

[image: abap dynpro listbox with 2 countries]

For information, you can achieve the same result from the database table of countries `T005T`, by transferring the entries to an intermediate internal table:

```
  DATA: lt_t005t TYPE TABLE OF t005t,
        ls_t005t TYPE t005t.
  SELECT * FROM t005t
      INTO TABLE lt_t005t
      WHERE spras = 'E' " English names of countries
        AND land1 IN ('FR','DE').
  LOOP AT lt_t005t INTO ls_t005t.
    ls_value-key = ls_t005t-land1.
    ls_value-text = ls_t005t-landx50.
    APPEND ls_value TO lt_value.
  ENDLOOP.
```

You may find more information in the SAP Library (the explanations are valid for all kind of screens, the examples are only for classic screens but they may be adapted easily to selection screens): http://help.sap.com/saphelp_470/helpdata/en/9f/dbabe435c111d1829f0000e829fbfe/frameset.htm

Comment: Hi  But is there only way of calling this FM or if it is normal report program. how do i achieve it ???. Other than this FM any other way is there... Thanks

Comment: You can still call this function module by using the AT SELECTION-SCREEN ON VALUE REQUEST FOR L1 event.

Comment: @Siva, Sorry, I didn't realize it is a report program. +1 for Esti's comment.