# Filling parameter with value from Zeconfig_var table

Tags: abap, dropdownbox

I have the following selection parameter:

```
PARAMETERS: p_ver(2)   AS LISTBOX VISIBLE LENGTH 5.
```

I would like to populate it with the results from a ZECONFIG_VAR table.

At what point would I do this.  Selection Screen Output, Start of Selection, or other.  I am trying to allow users the ability to decide what version of the web service they would like to call.  The config table will have different url's for the different versions.

I have looked at this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847534/how-to-set-values-in-the-listbox) and the tutorial provided does not make sense to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set values in the listbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847534/how-to-set-values-in-the-listbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esti is right that you probably want to fill an internal table from the DB table during `INITIALIZATION`.

But to the populate the listbox parameter, you need to put the call to `VRM_SET_VALUES` in `AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT`.

Comment: Ah good to know, although I've never done this - I always use data dictionary elements that don't make me think :).

Comment: The VRM_SET_VALUES function does not give me the option to select from a config table.  The table I want to select from is external from the program.

Comment: Correct, you will need to read the values from the table yourself first, then populate a table of type VRM_VALUES and pass it to the function VRM_SET_VALUES via the VALUES parameter.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it at the event INITIALIZATION

However, it may be even easier to just create a search-help, and assign it to p_ver using the following:

```
parameters: p_ver(2) visible lenghth 5 MATCHCODE OBJECT zshelpname.
```