# Transparent Table into Dropdown-List ABAP

Tags: database, listbox, abap, internal-tables

Putting Fields of internal tables into listboxes is easy but how do you do it with transparent tables?
Please the easiest possible way. (Important: Te Table shouldn't be changed!)

Comment: By first transferring the transparent table to the internal table (`SELECT`).

Comment: Can you give an simple example of the syntax

Comment: [SELECT in ABAP documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapselect.htm) (example at bottom of page)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set values in the listbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847534/how-to-set-values-in-the-listbox)

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to do it with internal table, then Transparent tables (database tables) each have a structure with the same name, that you can use to create an internal table. Tthis is more or less all you need:

```
data: lt_mara type standard table of mara. "Define internal table with structure type of a transparent table
select * from mara into @lt_mara up to 100 rows. "Select your data
```

Keep in mind that this is a very basic select statement. To retrieve the data you need (and not first 100 rows) you can look into

- SQL in general. Common principles are the same and more popular languages tend to have better summaries
- OpenSQL/AbapSQL(different versions of the same thing) for info about SQL you use in abap.